# Alternative expressions for "it shows" or "it can be seen"

Tags: vocabulary

I am writing an analytical essay but don't know what expressions I can use instead of

`it shows when` or `it can be seen when`

Are there any phrase or words I can use instead?

I am analysing a book and I don't really know how to vary the expressions in my writing when I want to analyse certain situations in the story. For example, how else could I say,

> It shows when the character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple alternatives that come to mind:

1. **evident (or *evinced by*)**

   > The character's complete lack of basic human morals is **evident in**/**evinced by** his mistreatment of the homeless man.
2. **apparent (*in*)**

   > The narrator loses the will to live when he learns of his father's death. This is **apparent** in his notable change in tone and sudden loss of interest in his work.
3. **conveyed (*by* or *through*)**

   > The main character's thoughts are scattered. This is **conveyed through** the author's use of numerous run-on sentences and ellipses.
4. **suggest(s)**

   > The protagonist lies when the police officer asks him about his involvement in the shooting. This **suggests** he is hiding something—even from the readers.

Answer (score 0):

is **manifest** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/manifest)

> Clearly apparent to the sight or understanding; obvious.

As in:

> The character's hunger is manifest as he eats the apple.

Answer (score -1):

A few other ways of saying "The character's hunger shows/can be seen when he eats an apple" are:

- The character's hunger **is apparent when** he eats an apple.
- The character's eating an apple **reveals/highlights** his hunger **to the reader**.
- The character's hunger **is illustrated by** his eating an apple.